# ionic-cordova-SQLite possible to insert a Array as parameter?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I just wrote a simple function, that creates me a INSERT string out of the input the user has made, so I get something like this(working with ionic btw):

```
    INSERT INTO people(firstname, lastname) VALUES (??)
```

Now I would like to use a Array that holds the inputvalues as parameter:

```
let inputvalues = ["value1", "value2"];
    this.database.executeSql(this.createInserString("people",this.userData), [inputvalues]).then((data) => {
        console.log("INSERTED: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR-Insert: " + JSON.stringify(error.err));
    });
```

Is there a way to implement something like this? (because otherwise I have to type out ever single input values and ... there are a lot ;-( )

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you should separate parameters with comma:

```
INSERT INTO people(firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?)
```

and then use the array without "[ ]" since its already an array:

```
this.database.executeSql(this.createInserString("people",this.userData), inputvalues)
```

Comment: Uh jeah, the comma was just a typo ;-) Thank you, that worked! Now I feel stupid ;D